# Find first Movie file in every subfolder and create txt file with same name

Tags: loops, batch-file

I would like the batch scriptto find the first movie file(with first i mean alphabeticly first) in all the subfolders and create a txt-file with the same name. I got as far as getting all the Folders that contain the files. with the first for-loop but the second doesn't seem to work as intended
Movie formats: wmv mkv mp4 avi

```
@echo off
set CurDir=%CD%
for /f "tokens=*" %%G in ('dir /b /s /a:d %CurDir%') do (
    For /f "tokens=*" %%H in ('dir /A:-D "%%G"') do (
        echo %%H
    )
)
echo %CurDir%
pause
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dos
@echo off
    setlocal enableextensions disabledelayedexpansion
    set "curdir=%CD%"

    for /r "%curdir%" /d %%d in (*) do (
        pushd "%%~fd" && (
            set "first=1"
            for /f "delims=" %%a in ('
                dir /b /a-d /on *.wmv *.mkv *.mp4 *.avi 2^>nul
            ') do if defined first (
                set "first="
                type nul > "%%~nxa.txt"
            )
            popd
        )
    )
```

For each folder in the structure, change to the folder and for each file in the list if it is the first one in the folder generate the txt file using the name and extension of the found file.

Comment: Thanks this works, however i still get a lot of "files not found". Perhaps this i due to asian characters? as far as i can tell it will still generate the text file

Comment: I figured out that the "file not found" error message generated by your script is caused if the directory does not have a movie file. Is there a way to fix it?

Comment: @Hazmat, errors corrected. While redirecting the full `for` stderr stream to nul performs better, I prefer to place the redirection in the command that needs it, else any other error message could not be detected.

Comment: Thank you for your help i tried adding de nul to the same spot as you, but didn't work because i didn't have the ^ in there, is my guess

Comment: @Hazmat, `>` is a special character, and must not be interpreted by the main batch parser, but by the `cmd` instance started inside the `for /f`, so it is necessary to escape it. The reason for the `^`